# Prevent load code in specified page joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

im a newbie of Joomla and Virtuemart, i have added some code in index.php and i want to prevent load those code in specified pages, example "Virtuemart cart view", how can i do this? thanks

Comment: We could probably help you more if you provided some code for us to have context for commenting on...

Comment: What cppl said plus it is doubtful the adding code to index.php is the way to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all the code directly in index.php is bad practise if you need to do something like that try module concept then you will get option to display it in menu wise.

Here you are using code in index.php the you should check page with if(){} like

```
$task = JRequest::getVar('task');
$option= JRequest::getVar('option');
$view = JRequest::getVar('view');

if($view == "cart" && $option == "com_virtuemart" && $task== "somthing") :
// your code section.
endif;
```

hope this will help you..